# Hibernate executeUpdate() throws exception for PostgreSQL native query with returning *

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, sql-returning

Hibernate `executeUpdate()` for insert or update native query  with `returning *` gives and exception and also does not update the tables.

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(
      "INSERT INTO public.account (username) VALUES ('xx'), ('yy'), ('zz') RETURNING user_id");

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
query.executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
```

Exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.

Answer (score 2):

`executeUpdate()` is only appropriate if the SQL statement does not return result rows.

Use `iterate()`, `list()` or `scroll()` instead.